# AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'date' on import yaml

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyyaml

one of my code lines is

```
import yaml
```

which was installed on python 3.7 using `pip install pyyaml`

the following error arises

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
>   "C:/code/EPMD/Kodex/Applications/EPMD-Software/Sandbox/peer_changing_send_rate.py",
>   line 1, in 
>       from TestPeer.TestPeerChangingSendRate import TestPeerChangingSendSpeed
>        File "C:\code\EPMD\Kodex\Applications\EPMD-Software\TestPeer\TestPeerChangingSendRate.py",
>
> line 1, in 
>       from .TestPeer import TestPeer
>        File "C:\code\EPMD\Kodex\Applications\EPMD-Software\TestPeer\TestPeer.py",
>
> line 4, in 
>       from BaseProcess.ZmqPeerClass import ZmqPeer
>        File "C:\code\EPMD\Kodex\Applications\EPMD-Software\BaseProcess\ZmqPeerClass.py",
>
> line 2, in 
>       from .ZmqPublisherClass import ZmqPublisher
>        File "C:\code\EPMD\Kodex\Applications\EPMD-Software\BaseProcess\ZmqPublisherClass.py",
>
> line 10, in 
>       from . import ZmqProcessClass
>        File "C:\code\EPMD\Kodex\Applications\EPMD-Software\BaseProcess\ZmqProcessClass.py",
>
> line 5, in 
>       from .ConfigBaseClass import ConfigBase
>        File "C:\code\EPMD\Kodex\Applications\EPMD-Software\BaseProcess\ConfigBaseClass.py",
>
> line 3, in 
>       import yaml
>        File "C:\code\EPMD\Kodex\venv\lib\site-packages\yaml__init__.py", line 9, in 
>       from .dumper import *
>        File "C:\code\EPMD\Kodex\venv\lib\site-packages\yaml\dumper.py", line 6, in 
>       from .representer import *
>        File "C:\code\EPMD\Kodex\venv\lib\site-packages\yaml\representer.py", line
>
> 263, in 
>       SafeRepresenter.add_representer(datetime.date,     AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'date'

How to I get `import yaml` to work?

Comment: Do you happen to have a `datetime.py` file in any of the directories shown in the error messsage? If you do then rename it

Comment: wow I wouldn't catch that ever! If you could explain your thought process, i would be more than happy

Comment: I added a more through answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a file called `datetime.py` in one of the directories shown in the error message (most probably `C:/code/EPMD/Kodex/Applications/EPMD-Software/Sandbox/`), if you do then you need to rename it to something that will not shadow any other Python module.

The reasoning is that it masks the actual `datetime` module, since files/directories/modules in the current working directory have precedence over the modules installed in the `site-packages` directory (in which the built-in and installed modules live). If both locations contain an `a` module then `import a` will import the local `a` module instead of the (probably) intended `a` module from `site-packages`.

When `yaml\representer.py` did `import datetime` it imported your `datetime.py` file/module which does not have a `date` attribute, which is why an `AttributeError` was raised when it later tried to use `datetime.date`.